# How to get timezone without cookies set in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, cookies

I am developing `Rails-4 application` where I created 1 form for users.

Users from all `over around the world`. Now, I have to `get timezone` also of users which fill form without enter or select `timezone`.

I already used `javascript cookies method` and its work perfect like below code:

```
function set_time_zone_offset() {
    var current_time = new Date();
    $.cookie('time_zone', current_time.getTimezoneOffset());
}
```

But problem when someone not allow cookies or clear cookies of them browser at that time issue of timezone. Timezone get blank that i have issue in my application.

now, `without timezone set in cookies`, is there any way to get timezone in hidden field which post with form so i can save it.

Thanks

Comment: you are doing just this to get the timezone of user and display time in local time to the user?

Comment: There is already post, look at it if it helps you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12326570/rails-how-to-get-the-current-users-time-zone-when-using-heroku

Comment: You should check this out. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25243240/how-can-i-use-javascript-to-get-the-local-time-in-a-rails-form) this is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JsTimezoneDetect](https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect) Library for getting the timezone reliably.

Here's [how](http://thisbythem.com/blog/clientside-timezone-detection/) you can use it in Rails app.

[Cdn link](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jstimezonedetect).